# Javascript grid layout buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects

I have a grid of 24 buttons (please see the snippet 1) done with CSS. My question is if the same effect can be obtained with JavaScript and the buttons to act like radio buttons (only 1 button to be selected at 1 time).

As an example of what I try to achieve is snippet 2. The problem with the example 2 is based jquery instead of js and it has a huge slow library....I was looking for several examples but most of them are JQ rather than JS...

Any help or pointing to the right direction is highly appreciated.

Thank you

```css
.btn_sq {
 display : inline;
 box-sizing : content-box;
 width : 28px;
 height : 28px;
 margin : 2px;
 padding : 10px;
 border : 1px solid #018dc4;
 border-radius : 3px;
 text-align : center;
 font : normal normal bold 24px/normal Verdana,  Geneva,  sans-serif;
 cursor : pointer;
}
.btn_sq:hover {
 display : inline-block;
 color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border : 1px solid #007cad;
 background : rgba(58, 187, 234, 1);
 box-shadow : 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 transition : all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
.btn_week:active {
 color : purple;
 border : 1px solid #018dc4;
 background : rgba(186, 18, 209, 1);
 box-shadow : 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
 text-shadow : none;
 transition : all 50ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="1" id="w1"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="2" id="w2"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="3" id="w3"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="4" id="w4"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="5" id="w5"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="6" id="w6"/><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="7" id="w7"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="8" id="w7"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="9" id="w9"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="10" id="w10"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="11" id="w11"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="12" id="w12"/><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="13" id="w13" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="14" id="w14" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="15" id="w15" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="16" id="w16" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="17" id="w17" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="18" id="w18" /><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="19" id="w19" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="20" id="w20" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="21" id="w21" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="22" id="w22" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="23" id="w23" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="24" id="w24" />
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Display as grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 
  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ol>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Javascript code which follows JQuery UI Coding standards:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Display as grid</title>
 
 
  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .default { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  
  <script>
    function hasClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList)
        return el.classList.contains(className)
      else
        return !!el.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'))
    }
    
    function addClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList)
        el.classList.add(className)
      else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
    }
    
    function removeClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList)
        el.classList.remove(className)
      else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
        el.className=el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="default">1</li>
  <li class="default">2</li>
  <li class="default">3</li>
  <li class="default">4</li>
  <li class="default">5</li>
  <li class="default">6</li>
  <li class="default">7</li>
  <li class="default">8</li>
  <li class="default">9</li>
  <li class="default">10</li>
  <li class="default">11</li>
  <li class="default">12</li>
</ol>

<script>
  var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("default");

  var myFunction = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
        removeClass(classname[i], 'selected');
      }
      //alert(attribute);
      addClass(this, 'selected');
  };
  
  for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
  }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result , use .btn_sq:focus instead of .btn_week:active which seems to not available

```css
.btn_sq {
 display : inline;
 box-sizing : content-box;
 width : 28px;
 height : 28px;
 margin : 2px;
 padding : 10px;
 border : 1px solid #018dc4;
 border-radius : 3px;
 text-align : center;
 font : normal normal bold 24px/normal Verdana,  Geneva,  sans-serif;
 cursor : pointer;
}
.btn_sq:hover {
 display : inline-block;
 color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border : 1px solid #007cad;
 background : rgba(58, 187, 234, 1);
 box-shadow : 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 transition : all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
.btn_sq:focus {
 color : purple;
 border : 1px solid #018dc4;
 background : rgba(186, 18, 209, 1);
 box-shadow : 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
 text-shadow : none;
 transition : all 50ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="1" id="w1"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="2" id="w2"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="3" id="w3"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="4" id="w4"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="5" id="w5"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="6" id="w6"/><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="7" id="w7"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="8" id="w7"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="9" id="w9"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="10" id="w10"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="11" id="w11"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="12" id="w12"/><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="13" id="w13" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="14" id="w14" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="15" id="w15" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="16" id="w16" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="17" id="w17" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="18" id="w18" /><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="19" id="w19" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="20" id="w20" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="21" id="w21" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="22" id="w22" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="23" id="w23" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="24" id="w24" />
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oqEbKW

**Option 2:**

Using Javascript same result can be achieved using document.getElementsByClassName and for loop

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_sq');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
      removeBackground();
      this.style.background = "red"
    })
}

function removeBackground(){
   for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].style.background = ""
}
}
```

code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JLpXXN

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn_sq');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
      removeBackground();
      this.style.background = "red"
    })
}

function removeBackground(){
   for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].style.background = ""
}
}
```

```css
.btn_sq {
 display : inline;
 box-sizing : content-box;
 width : 28px;
 height : 28px;
 margin : 2px;
 padding : 10px;
 border : 1px solid #018dc4;
 border-radius : 3px;
 text-align : center;
 font : normal normal bold 24px/normal Verdana,  Geneva,  sans-serif;
 cursor : pointer;
}
.btn_sq:hover {
 display : inline-block;
 color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border : 1px solid #007cad;
 background : rgba(58, 187, 234, 1);
 box-shadow : 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 transition : all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="1" id="w1"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="2" id="w2"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="3" id="w3"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="4" id="w4"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="5" id="w5"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="6" id="w6"/><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="7" id="w7"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="8" id="w7"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="9" id="w9"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="10" id="w10"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="11" id="w11"/>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="12" id="w12"/><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="13" id="w13" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="14" id="w14" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="15" id="w15" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="16" id="w16" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="17" id="w17" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="18" id="w18" /><br>
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="19" id="w19" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="20" id="w20" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="21" id="w21" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="22" id="w22" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="23" id="w23" />
      <input type="button" class="btn_sq" value="24" id="w24" />
```

Comment: Ahh thank you for pointing that... forgot to change when I copied in code sniped... stii my initial question stays... can be this reproduced in javascript...

Comment: yes , solution which I have provided uses only CSS and HTML without jQuery